# how to scale down the output of model in the data where we normalized the data based on a custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I normalized the data for training and testing the **LSTM** model as:

`x_normalized = (x_unnormalized-x_min)/(x_max-x_min).`

x_min, x_max are the minimum and maximum of  each entire rows.

Same as the figure, I choose the last column as the test data.

The model works and etc. However, in this condition, the `y_prediction` is normalized. I don't know how to see the `y_prediction` in the real value.
There is any simple solution for that?[image]

Here is the simple code and the normalization:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x1'] = [ 1, 2,4]
df['x2'] = [ 5, 9, 5]
df['x3'] = [ 3, 21, 10 ]
df['x4'] = [ 8, 32,3 ]
df['x5'] = [ 8, 32,15 ]
df['x6'] = [ 2, 5,15 ]

def norm(df):
    MIN = df.min(1)
    MAX = df.max(1)
    return df.sub(MIN, 0).div(MAX-MIN, 0)

df_normalized = norm(df)
train        = df_normalized.iloc[:, 0:5] 
test         = df_normalized.iloc[:, 5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your formula:

```
x_unnormalized = x_normalized*(x_max-x_min) + x_min
```

So you just need to save the values of x_max and x_min of the original dataframe and then have a function executing the formula above